# Extracting data from html using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract the text within all the 'a' tags from this code, i get an error:

(AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?)

What am i doing wrong?

```
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime
from discord import Webhook, RequestsWebhookAdapter
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed
import discord
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from discord.ext import commands

r = requests.get("https://www.hypedc.com/nz/nike-air-force-1-07-black-black-cw2288-001")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
size = soup.find('div', id="size-selector-tab-mobile-0")
size = size.find_all('li', class_='col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4')
size = size.find_all('a').text
print(size)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show any attempt to find `'a'` tags.

Comment: "but this didn't work" what error message?

Comment: OK let me fix the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `size.find_all('li', class_='col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4')` return a list. So you need to iterate it to get the size.

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.hypedc.com/nz/nike-air-force-1-07-black-black-cw2288-001")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
size = soup.find('div', id="size-selector-tab-mobile-0")

size = size.find_all('li') # return list

for t in size:
    print(t.a.text.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the help

Comment: please mark answer as accepted if it correctly solved your issue :)